# How can I safely access management RPC calls on a remote server?

Tags: go-ethereum, json-rpc

I read in many places that you should not expose the [management](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Management-APIs) APIs when running a `geth` node. If this is the case, how can I access these APIs if I must do so on a remote server?

If the server is protected (password/priv key/etc.), can someone still access the node? Does the `--rpccorsdomain "*"` have anything to do with it?

Comment: You can use a tunnel with ssh .